# How can I use variables to decide what to change on a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, variables, dom, literals

I am writing a function to iterate over an array that will determine what gets changed in an element. I have tried a few ideas including template literals but am not achieving desired results. Any ideas how to pass desired dom changes through an array into a function?

```
testArray = [["background", "yellow"]];

const changeElement =(id, array)=>{
    let element = getElementById(id);

    for(let i = 0; i<=array.length-1; i++){
      for(let j = 0; j<=array.length-1; j++){
       `${element}.style.${array[i][j]} = "${array[i][j+1]}"`;  
    }}
}
```

Comment: Why do you iterate again over array inside of first for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need template literals. It won't work.

Simply using rectangular brackets (`[ ]`) will work for you.

In JavaScript, you can access the properties of objects using the dot (`.`) operator or using rectangular brackets (`[ ]`).

For example, if you have an object as follows:

```
var obj = {
    x: "Hii",
    y: 5,
};
```

Now if you want to access `x` of `obj`, you can access it in 2 ways:

```
console.log(obj.x); // Hii

// This will also work
console.log(obj["x"]); // Hii
```

Similarly, for `y`:

```
console.log(obj.y); // 5

// This will also work
console.log(obj["y"]); // 5
```

Now, in this case, `element.style` is an object. If you want to access property `background` of `element.style`, you can do the following:

```
// This won't work for your case as the property to be modified is stored in array
element.style.background = "yellow";

// But this will work!
element.style["background"] = "yellow";
```

So, while iterating, you can do this:

```
let testArray = [["background", "yellow"]]; 

const changeElement =(id, array) => { 
    let element = document.getElementById(id); 

    for(let i = 0; i<=array.length-1; i++){ 
        for(let j = 0; j<=array.length-1; j++){ 
            element.style[array[i][j]] = array[i][j+1];
        }
    } 
}
```

But I think your `testArray` will have this format:

```
let testArray = [["prop1", "value1"], ["prop2", "value2"], ... ];
```

If so, your code will not work and can be simplified to use just one `for` loop as follows:

```
  let testArray = [["background", "yellow"], ["color", "red"]]; 

const changeElement =(id, array) => { 
    let element = document.getElementById(id); 

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
        element.style[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in such detail.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use Object.fromEntries to transform testArray into

```js
{
    background: "yellow"
}
```

and then iterate through this object.

2) look at this

```js
const changeElement = (id, array)=>{
    const element = document.getElementById(id);

    for(let i = 0; i<=array.length-1; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j<=array.length-1; j++){
            element.style[array[i][j]] = array[i][j+1];
        }
    }
}

changeElement("myId", [["background", "yellow"]]);
```

you can get the value from an object by parentheses

3) You shouldn't using for loop. You can write less by using Array.prototype.forEach e.g.

```js
const changeElement = (id, array)=>{
    const element = document.getElementById(id);

    array.forEach(value => {
        element.style[value[0]] = value[1];
    });
}

changeElement("myId", [["background", "yellow"]]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/map

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer me back. I also appreciate being pointed toward some resources.